# How to take out specific letters from a character variable

Tags: r, substring, strsplit

```
xcv(123)
wert(232)
t(145)
tyui ier(133)
ytie(435)
...
```

The length of the string is dynamic meaning it is random. The number between the brackets are the target letters that are required to be taken out & stored in a new column in the same data set.

The following key words might help:
`substr()` `strsplit()`

I'm actively looking for an answer. Your help would be deeply appreciated.

Comment: You can do `library(stringr); str_extract(v1, "(?<=\\()[0-9]+(?=\\))")` or another option is `library(readr);parse_number(v1)`

Comment: In your last string you have `435` but your word only has 4 letters (assuming that I understood this correctly). You should add your expected output. Same with the second

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean you want to extract the, for example, 123rd letter from the string called `xcv`?

```
set.seed(123)
xcv <- paste( sample( letters, 200, replace = TRUE ), collapse = "" )
n <- 123
```

You can extract the `n`th letter like so:

```
substr( xcv, n, n )

# [1] "i"
```

Answer (score 0):

---

```
dat = c('xcv(123)' ,'wert(232)', 't(145)', 'tyui ier(133)', 'ytie(435)')
target = gsub(".*\\(|\\).*", "", dat) #captures anything in between '(' and ')'. We use \\( and \\) to denote the brackets since they are special characters.
cbind(dat, target) 

     dat             target
[1,] "xcv(123)"      "123" 
[2,] "wert(232)"     "232" 
[3,] "t(145)"        "145" 
[4,] "tyui ier(133)" "133" 
[5,] "ytie(435)"     "435"
```